# Condition for differentiable functional - Why is it defined in this exact way?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity, calculus-of-variations

I'm kind of struggling to understand, why the condition

> $$J\left[y+h\right]-J\left[y\right] = \Psi \left[h\right]+\varepsilon
>  \left(h\right){\lVert}h{\rVert} $$
>
> where $\Psi$ is a linear functional, and $\varepsilon(h)$ is a
> functional such that $\varepsilon(h) \rightarrow 0 $ for
> ${\lVert}h{\rVert} \rightarrow 0$

is the condition to check if we want to know if our given functional $J\left[\cdot \right]$ is differentiable or not.

Should we divide both sides by $\varepsilon(h)$, and take the limit ${\lVert}h{\rVert} \rightarrow 0$, and see what happens?

Also, I know, that if $\varepsilon(h) \rightarrow 0 $ for  ${\lVert}h{\rVert} \rightarrow 0$, then $\varepsilon(h)$ is a continuous functional - but why? Shouldn't continuity be checked by taking the difference ${\lVert}\varepsilon(f_n) - \varepsilon (f){\rVert}$ and checking if it's $\rightarrow 0$ for ${\lVert}f_n - f{\rVert} \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: it's defined that way because differential calculus is the study of local linear approximations (and this also conforms with our usual intuitive understanding in terms of slopes). See [Defining differentiablity of a function of two variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3298644/568204) for the motivation, and also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3802166/568204). The definition of differentiability can be given in much [more generality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3662806/568204). For your next question, we have $\epsilon(0):=0$ and so $\epsilon$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Continuity of $\epsilon$ at the origin can be described either directly ($\epsilon(h)\to 0$ as $h\to 0$), or in terms of sequences: for every sequence $\{h_n\}$ such that $h_n\to 0$, we require $\epsilon(h_n)\to 0$.

Comment: But if we have $J\left[y+h\right]-J\left[y\right] = \Psi \left[h\right]+\varepsilon
 \left(h\right){\lVert}h{\rVert} $, then by what should we divide both sides to actually calculate the functional derivative? Should we divide by $\varepsilon(h)$, or should we divide by ${\lVert}h{\rVert} $? If I had to guess, we should be dividing both sides by ${\lVert}h{\rVert} $ because then it'd be $\lim _{{\lVert}h{\rVert}\to 0}\frac{J\left[y+h\right]-J\left[y\right]\:}{{\lVert}h{\rVert}}$, just like in the definition of the derivative of a function?

Comment: The functional derivative is the linear mapping $\Psi$; typically denoted as $DJ_y$ or $dJ_y$ or in the calculus of variations, $\delta J_y$, or simply $\delta J$. Calculating $\Psi$ means figuring out what is $\Psi(h)$ for all possible $h$. One possible way of doing to is that $\Psi(h)=DJ_y(h)$ (the Frechet derivative of $J$ at $h$) and by the chain rule, this is equal to $\frac{d}{ds}\bigg|_{s=0}J(y+sh)=\lim\limits_{s\to 0}\frac{J(y+sh)-J(y)}{s}$. i.e $\Psi(h)=DJ_y(h)=\frac{d}{ds}\bigg|_{s=0}J(y+sh)=\lim\limits_{s\to 0}\frac{J(y+sh)-J(y)}{s}$.

Comment: This is like saying if you have a differentiable function, then knowing all the directional derivatives determines the "total" derivative. In the calculus of variations, it is usually most convenient to calculate this directional derivative for all possible $h$, thereby determining what $\Psi=DJ_y$ is.

Answer (score 0):

apping Ψ; typically denoted as DJy or dJy or in the calculus of variations, δJy, or simply δJ. Calculating Ψ means figuring out what is Ψ(h) for all possible h. One possible way of doing to is that Ψ(h)=DJy(h) (the Frechet derivative of J at h) and by the chain rule, this is equal to dds∣∣∣s=0J(y+sh)=lims→0J(y+sh)−J(y)s. i.e Ψ(h)=DJy(h)=dds∣∣∣s=0J(y+sh)=lims→0J(y+sh)−J(y

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).