# Partial derivatives and differentiability, continuity

Tags: derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

Function $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has in every $x$ of domain partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x) =x_2$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(x) =x_1$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}(x) =x_3$. Determine whether

- a) $f$ is continous
- b) $f$ is differentiable

How to do that without knowing $f$'s formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Theorem: $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is $\mathcal C^1$ (continuously differentiable) $\iff$ $f$ has continuous partial derivatives.

Proof of Sufficiency: [Proof that continuous partial derivatives implies differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007709/proof-that-continuous-partial-derivatives-implies-differentiability)

> Conclusion

$f$ is differentiable.