# Why is $\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}$ not differentiable at origin?

Tags: calculus

Why $$\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}$$ is not differentiable at origin?

Comment: Not differentiable where?  With respect to what?  And who said it isn't?

Comment: my calculus teacher said that it is continuous at the origin but it is not differentiable... but i don't understand why...
As long as I remember, for a function to be differentiable, just be continuous and exist on the point.

Comment: It looks perfectly differentiable (with gradient zero) to me.

Comment: @AugustoAmaral, you could try follow the definition of multi-variable derivative

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. All partial derivatives of this function exist and are continuous, so the function is differentiable infinitely often everywhere.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. All partial derivatives of this function exist and are continuous, so the function is differentiable infinitely often everywhere.

Comment: @Covvar , I'm sorry for bad English :(

Comment: Consider $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ instead; that function is continuous but not differentiable at the origin.

Comment: @AugustoAmaral, "continuous and existing" aren't enough for differentiability.  The limit that defines the derivative must exist (although maybe that's what you meant).  For example, $|x|$ exists and is continuous at $x=0$, but it is not differentiable there because the limit that defines the derivative does not exist, since the limit from the left is $-1$ and from the right is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

This function is differentiable at the origin. The easiest way to see this is that the function has continuous partials at $(0,0)$. You can look at this post for this theorem. [Proof that continuous partial derivatives implies differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007709/proof-that-continuous-partial-derivatives-implies-differentiability)

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I didn't understand why my calculator said that ..