# Ahlfors Proof of Cauchy-Riemann

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

In proving the sufficient condition, Ahlfors claims that if $u(x,y)$ has a continuous, first order partials, then we can write $$u(x+h,y+k) - u(x,y) = \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial {x}}h +\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial {y}}k + \epsilon$$ where $\epsilon$ is little-o of $h +ik$. Now I am familiar with this definition for real functions of one variable (in fact I attempted a proof of it on a previous question), however I'm having difficulties seeing it given the limit definition of partials. Can anyone show a quick proof of this for 2 or n-variables.

Comment: You lost a $k$ in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous partial derivatives implies differentiability, can be found in many books of multivariable calculus, and [has been asked and proved here before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007709/proof-that-continuous-partial-derivatives-implies-differentiability).

[Differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions) implies that it can be written in such a form, with some linear function on $(h,k)$ in place of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}h+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}k$.

$$\begin{align}u(x+h,y+k)-u(x,y)&=L_{(x,y)}(h,k)+\epsilon\\L_{(x,y)}(h,k)&=ah+bk\end{align}$$

Restricting the limit in the definition of differentiability to the $X$-axis and then to the $Y$-axis you get that the linear function has coefficients $a=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $b=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$.