# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function. And $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ exist and continuous. Is $f$ a twice differenced function?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Obviously, it is true if $\delta>0$ imply $2f(x+\delta, y+\delta)-f(x+2\delta, y)-f(x, y+2\delta)=o(\delta^2)$. But this result I can't prove too.

Comment: I think it is anouth to proof that f_xy exist.

Comment: It is true. $f$ is differentiable if the partial derivatives exist and are continuous

Comment: @SydAmerikaner But how can I prove this?

Comment: see for example here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007709/proof-that-continuous-partial-derivatives-implies-differentiability

Comment: @SydAmerikaner I don't see how the result at that link applies here.

Comment: If all partial derivatives exist and are continuous. This is the result in the link. So if one can prove that $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ exist and are continuous, so is the derivative of $f$ differentiable, i.e. the second derivative of $f$ exists.

Comment: @SydAmerikaner But how do we show $f_{xy}$ even exists?