# Showing that $f(x,y)\sim f(x_0,y_0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Delta y$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$. I want to show that

$$f(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Delta y +\epsilon (x,y)$$

where $e\rightarrow 0$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow (x_0,y_0)$.

---

The idea I have in mind is that of

$$f(x,y)\sim f(x_0,y) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Delta x\sim f(x_0,y_0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Delta y$$

The last approximation can be proven easily by regarding $f$ as a function of $y$ alone: let $f_{x_0}(y)=f(x_0,y)$ and note that $$f_{x_0}(y)=f_{x_0}(y_0)+\frac{df}{dy}\Delta y +\epsilon _y\Delta y$$ where $$\epsilon _y =\Big( \frac{f_{x_0}(y)-f_{x_0}(y_0)}{\Delta y}-\frac{df}{dy}\Big) \rightarrow 0 \ \ \text{as} \ \ \Delta y\rightarrow 0$$

Yet I can't prove the first approximation.

---

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What _exactly_ is your definition of derivative?  (If you only require the existence of partials along the coordinate axes, then your goal is not true.)

Comment: That is no different from showing $f$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0).$ Is that what you really want to show?

Comment: @JacobManaker I had not noticed that just requiring the partial derivatives to exist along the coordinate axes was not enough, but you are right. I believe that if we assume the total derivative exists ar $(x_0,y_0)$ then the result would follow, right?

Comment: @zhw.how would $f$ being continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$ yield the result?

Comment: can you write down the definition of $f$ being differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: @Leo: Yes; that is the essence of Prado's solution.

Comment: As others have stated, the continuity is enough to show it for an arbitrary error $\epsilon(x,y).$ Basically, for any pair of continuous functions that passes through the same point $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (x_0,y_0)} f(x,y)-g(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0)-g(x_0,y_0) = 0$$ which means that your error converges to zero. On the other hand, not aways you substitute $f$ for any other function that passes through the same point. This would be like saying $f(x)=x^2$ looks like $g(x)=100x$ around the origin, just because both are zero there. Usually, some control on the error is needed, like "my concern" required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any differentiable function satisfies it by definition of differentiability, since it implies the existence of a vector $v$ (it can be seen as a [linear functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form#Linear_functionals_in_Rn)) such that $$ \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (x_0,y_0)}
\dfrac{f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)-\left(v_1 (x-x_0)+v_2(y-y_0)\right)}{|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|}=0
$$ After that, it's easy to see that partial derivatives is the components of the vector $v$, since $$0 = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f((x_0,y_0)+t e_i)-f(x_0,y_0)-t v_i}{t},$$ for $i=1$ and $i=2$, where $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$. There is no need of being a big brain here, for more details see [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition). On the other hand, a function with continuous [partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) is differentiable, see [the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007709/proof-that-continuous-partial-derivatives-implies-differentiability), and that is what you were trying to do in your last paragraph. All this things is basically stated in [Stewart](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0538498706).

Here, my only concern is about your $\epsilon(x,y)$ error. It needs to be a term of the form $$\epsilon(x,y) = (|x−x_0|+|y−y_0|)g(x,y),$$ with $g(x,y)$ converging to zero as $(x,y)\rightarrow(x_0,y_0)$. After that, it's easy to see that what you are wanting to show is the definition of differentability.